# Bootstrap 3 input-group with and without input-group-addon not spanning the same width

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know there are a lot of questions regarding input groups and their size in bootstrap 3, but I've tried every solution and I can't get it working properly (ie. with col-*-12). I've solved it temporarly messing around with col-xs-14 (yeah, I don't know why 14 works and 12 not).

I would be very thankful if someone can give me a solution with col-*-12 or an explanation of why 14 and not 12. And... the limit was not supposed to be 12 columns per row?

I've also read Bootstrap 3 documentation about the Grid System.

My working example can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/vicaba/eeeab161ccda8c49066d): index12.html uses col-xs-12 (not displaying properly) and index14.html uses col-xs-14 (displaying properly)

Comment: There is not such class of col-*-14 in the vanilla version of Bootstrap.

Comment: @ChrisYongchu WTF! I've removed it and it works! What a silly question then TT. Thank you!